# Hudson Shellscript for exporting Sourcecode from SVN repository into production folder

Tags: svn, lamp, hudson

I have one dedicated server which has the whole Lamp-Stack, SVN and Hudson installed. I would like to create a freestyle Hudson job, that gets the latest sourcecode out of my SVN-repository and puts it into my /var/www/myWebApp Folder.

How does the shell script need to look like?

Comment: For more answers on this question see the x-post on Stackoverflow.com http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185848/hudson-shellscript-for-exporting-sourcecode-from-svn-repository-into-production-f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not worried about history, this sounds fairly easy.  Keep in mind, this is NOT specific to Hudson--this is just a single SVN command.

```
svn export https://path/to/svn/repo /var/www/myWebApp
```

Andrew

Comment: Don't link your job to a repository, otherwise you would checkout the code to your working directory first.